# How to send welcome message AND load a specific dialog automatically in Microsoft Bot Framework v.3 (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying both to show a welcome message when my bot starts up and also load a specific dialog.  We are using version 3 in the company where I'm working (I know, it's old and not supported).

As far as the welcome message, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 says to use `on conversationUpdate`, which works fine, but this seems to be contradicted by https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/, which suggests one should *not* use `conversationUpdate`, except when using DirectLine, but instead send an event.  Is this the final word on the matter?  Is there a better way?

I'd also like to load a dialog automatically after the welcome message.  How do I do this?  Can I access the session during the 'on conversationUpdate' event above and load the dialog directly there?  Is there a better way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is contradictory, but `conversationUpdate` is likely your best bet in most situations. However, because channels handle this differently, you should be aware that the result can vary. For direct line, it is a better option to utilize sending events.

An example, in case of need:

```js
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function(message) {
  if (message.membersAdded) {
    message.membersAdded.forEach(function(identity) {
      if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
        var reply = new builder.Message()
          .address(message.address)
          .text("Welcome");
        bot.send(reply);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

For immediately calling a specific dialog, do this:

```js
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
  if (message.membersAdded) {
    message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
      if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
        bot.beginDialog(message.address, '/main');
      }
    });
  }
});

bot.dialog('/main', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    session.send("Glad you could join.");
    session.beginDialog('/next');
  }
]);
```

Simply combine the two for sending the welcome message and starting up a dialog.

Hope of help!