# How to start a dialog from welcome in bot framework javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-bot-service

I want to start a multilevel multichoice dialog from welcome in bot framework sdk with javascript.
I have the main  dialog (finalAnswerDialog) which call LUIS to predict intents, and a multilevel multichoice menu dialog (menuDialog) to guide the user to some intents. I want the bot to show the menu dialog from the beginning but I always get errors.
Here is my code:

**dialogAndWelcomeBot**

```
const { CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const { DialogBot } = require('./dialogBot');
const { ActivityHandler, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const { ActionTypes } = require('botframework-schema');
const { MenuDialog } = require('../dialogs/menuDialog');

class DialogAndWelcomeBot extends DialogBot {
    constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog) {
        super(conversationState, userState, dialog);
        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    await dialog.run(context, conversationState.createProperty('DialogState'));
                    await step.beginDialog('menuDialog');
                }
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}


module.exports.DialogAndWelcomeBot = DialogAndWelcomeBot;
```

**menuDialog** who calls finalAnswerDialog in order to manage LUIS calls at any point

```
class MenuDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(finalAnswerDialog) {
        super('menuDialog');

        this.answered=true;
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(NAME_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(finalAnswerDialog);

        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.firstQuestion.bind(this),
            this.secondQuestion.bind(this),
            this.thirdQuestion.bind(this),
            this.answerTheQuestion.bind(this),
            this.finalStep.bind(this)
        ]));
        
        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }
```

**finalAnswerDialog**

```
class FinalAnswerDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(luisRecognizer) {
        super('finalAnswerDialog');

        if (!luisRecognizer) throw new Error('[MainDialog]: Missing parameter \'luisRecognizer\' is required');
        this.luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;

        // Define the main dialog and its related components.
        // This is a sample "book a flight" dialog.
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt('TextPrompt'));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
                //this.initStep.bind(this),
                this.actStep.bind(this),

            ]));

        this.initialDialogId = MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }

    async run(turnContext, accessor) {
        const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
        dialogSet.add(this);

        const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);
        const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
        if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
            await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
        }
    }

    async initStep(stepContext) {
        return await stepContext.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, promptOptions);
    }

    async actStep(stepContext) {
        if (!this.luisRecognizer.isConfigured) {
            const messageText = 'NOTE: LUIS is not configured. To enable all capabilities, add `LuisAppId`, `LuisAPIKey` and `LuisAPIHostName` to the .env file.';
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(messageText, null, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
            return await stepContext.next();
        }

        const luisResult = await this.luisRecognizer.executeLuisQuery(stepContext.context);
        let top_intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult)
        //let top_intent="contacto"
        console.log("intent predicha por Luis: " + top_intent)
        
        switch (top_intent) {
//SendActivity
```

**index.js**

```
const dialog = new FinalAnswerDialog(luisRecognizer);
const bot = new DialogAndWelcomeBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);
```

How can I start the menu dialog in welcome?

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, you can start the specific(menu/any) dialog from welcome code.***

The key thing is here not to use `conversationUpdate` from your bot code, but rather submit an event activity from the client, and add some code to handle the event to your bot code.

To add an activity in the form of event handler, refer [how to send a greeting message and common issues](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/)

---

There is another solution which would be to store a map of user-id and session and then use seesion.send to send a dialog to the corresponding user. Using `conversationUpdate` is likely your best bet in most situations.

**Demo Welcome code:**

```js
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function(message) {
  if (message.membersAdded) {
    message.membersAdded.forEach(function(identity) {
      if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
        var reply = new builder.Message()
          .address(message.address)
          .text("Welcome");
        bot.send(reply);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**To call the specific dialog, do this:**

```js
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
  if (message.membersAdded) {
    message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
      if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
        bot.beginDialog(message.address, '/main');
      }
    });
  }
});

bot.dialog('/main', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    session.send("Glad you could join.");
    session.beginDialog('/next');
  }
]);
```

The above code is combination of welcome message and starting up a dialog.
Also you can find a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972954/how-to-send-welcome-message-and-load-a-specific-dialog-automatically-in-microsof) here.